# org.hibernate.MappingException: property [id.companyId] not found on entity

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, hibernate-mapping

I am in the process of upgrading from Hibernate 5.0 to 5.3 and I am running into an unexpected issue.

My Entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="USER_CUSTOMER_MAPPING",
    uniqueConstraints={ @UniqueConstraint( columnNames={ "USER_NAME", "COMPANY_ID", "CUSTOMER_ID" } ) })
@IdClass( UserCustomerMappingId.class )
public class UserCustomerMapping implements Cloneable, Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column( name="USER_NAME", nullable=false, updatable=false )
    @Index( name="USER_CUSTOMER_MAPPING_USER_NAME_INDEX" )
    @NotNull
    private String userName = null;

    @Id
    @Column( name="COMPANY_ID", nullable=false, length=100 )
    @Index( name="USER_CUSTOMER_MAPPING_COMPANY_ID_INDEX" )
    @NotNull
    @Length( max=100 )
    private String companyId = null;

    @Id
    @Column( name="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false )
    @Index( name="USER_CUSTOMER_MAPPING_CUSTOMER_ID_INDEX" )
    @NotNull
    private String customerId = null;

  // rest has been abbreviated for brevity
}
```

My composite key class looks like this:

```
public class UserCustomerMappingId implements Cloneable, Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String userName = null;
    private String companyId = null;
    private String customerId = null;

    public UserCustomerMappingId()
    {
        super();
    }

  // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The above works perfectly on Hibernate 5.0, but encounters the below MappingException when run deployed on Hibernate 5.3 (this is being encountered as I attempt to upgrade from WildFly 10 to WildFly 19). This occurs while the PersistenceUnit is starting.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: property [id.companyId] not found on entity [...UserCustomerMapping]
```

I have made no other source nor configuration changes, What am I missing or do I need to change to make the above work with Hibernate 5.3 (WildFly 19) please?

Comment: kindly bumped as I remain stumped on this one.  Any help will be greatly appreciated please.

Comment: I have recently discovered that the org.hibernate.MappingException can be avoided if I remove the &#64;Index annotation from the &#64;Id attributes in the &#64;Entity class.  This combination if &#64;Id and &#64;Index has worked well for me in Hibernate 5.0, but appears to be problematic in 5.3 (albeit not so obviously by the error message).

Can anyone shed any light on why this combination is now an issue?  Additionally, I want t have a named index on these columns, how can I restore the combination of the two annotations without encountering the MappingException?

Comment: I would still like to understand why the combination of `@Id` and `@Index` is no longer working. However, I have found a way to still declare the desire to have these indexes by specifying them as part of the `@Table` annotation.